# New problem with sound in Minecraft

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, pc, windows-10

Suddenly, in the middle of playing, the sound in Minecraft stops. Tried F3 + S/T, and to top it all off, this is what the volume mixer looks like (Sorry for the non-English language).

[image: Volume Mixer]

Minecraft version 1.10.2

Using Windows 10 (Did not have this problem before windows 10 update)

I am using a school pc, so specs are not great, but Minecraft runs fine.

While researching if people had a similar problem, I found no one whose sound suddenly stopped mid game. Also, I haven't seen anyone with a volume mixer like this. It is constantly at max, not changing at all, and no sound at all. (Other sounds work fine)

Restarting my PC fixes the issue, but only temporally. Any ideas?

Comment: Does the sound go out on other applications / games too?

Comment: This has happened to me too. Did you change your gamemode with commands when the music stopped? Minecraft has specific music for each gamemode, so when you switch it stops.

Comment: Are you using the latest Windows 10 October 2018 Update? That update causes many audio drivers to crash, especially on laptops. It must just be that your audio driver has crashed. Try updating your audio drivers to the latest version.

Answer (score 1):

This problem was happening for me as well. It is fixed by pressing the button that says [Video Settings] in the options, then changing the [Mipmap Levels]

Answer (score 0):

Try re-installing your audio drivers, and disabling other audio devices in "Playback Devices". You can also try updating Java and [OpenAL](https://www.openal.org/downloads/).

We could help you out more if you provided what audio peripherals (+ is it USB or 3.5mm or what), sound card/chipset, audio driver version(s), and PC specs you have.

Answer (score 0):

This could be a problem if you are using headphones. If you are using wireless headphones, this could be a problem with your headphones disconnecting and reconnecting without you noticing. Minecraft does not detect any audio output unless you have it connected when Minecraft starts up. If you use wired headphones, the wires in it could be loose and disconnecting, therefore causing Minecraft to not detect it anymore even though it is plugged in.